# Python set value of array which does not exist with 0 by default

Tags: python, arrays, csv, pandas, numpy

i have a input data from 'CTTR' column in csv file.

```
0
2
2
23
18
28
27
58
41
12
35
20
```

my code, i is the index

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("book1.csv")
vals = np.array(df['CTTR'])
new = np.array([vals[i-2] + 2*vals[i-1] + 4*vals[i] + 2*vals[i+1] + vals[i+2] for i in range(2,len(vals)-2)])/10.

for i in new:
    print i
```

but the output is not what i expeted. becuse some array does not exist when index [0],[1],[10] and [11]. i mean when index[0], vals[i-2] and vals[i-1] does not exist and my code skip this step.

the output

```
7.6
16.2
20.3
28.3
33.9
40.8
36.6
27.8
```

my expected output

```
0.6
3.5
7.6
16.2
20.3
28.3
33.9
40.8
36.6
27.8
24.5
16.2
```

so the amout of output same as the amount of input.
so how to set a value with 0 by default for array which does not exist?
for exmaple

```
[0] = (vals[i-2] + 2*vals[i-1] + 4*vals[i] + 2*vals[i+1] + vals[i+2])/10
[0] = (0 + 0 +4*0 + 2*2 + 2) /10
[0] = 0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [340]: list(range(2,len(vals)-2))
Out[340]: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

same number of values as in `new`, 8.

As for the question of how to get the end values; the list comprehension could be rewriten as a loop, with little loose in speed:

```
 alist = []
 for i in range(2,len(vals)-2):
    newval =  [vals[i-2] + 2*vals[i-1] + 4*vals[i] + 2*vals[i+1] + vals[i+2]
    alist.append(newval)
 np.array(alist)/10
```

for the extended range, we could throw in 'if' statements to handle the out of bounds cases:

```
 alist = []
 for i in range(len(vals)):
    if i<2: ...
    else:
         newval =  [vals[i-2] + 2*vals[i-1] + 4*vals[i] + 2*vals[i+1] + vals[i+2]
    alist.append(newval)
 np.array(alist)/10
```

Another option is to pad the array with some 0s

```
In [354]: vals1=np.concatenate(([0,0],vals,[0,0]))
In [355]: 
In [355]: new = np.array([vals1[i-2] + 2*vals1[i-1] + 4*vals1[i] + 2*vals1[i+1] 
     ...: + vals1[i+2] for i in range(2,len(vals1)-2)])/10.
In [356]: new
Out[356]: 
array([  0.6,   3.5,   7.6,  16.2,  20.3,  28.3,  33.9,  40.8,  36.6,
        27.8,  24.5,  16.2])
```